# Custom annotation view using MKCircle

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am trying to make a custom view for a custom MKAnnotation I have. What I want is a solid circle with a number inside, and a colour depending on what the value of that number is. The number's value will be taken from my custom MKAnnotation class. I currently have the annotation view as a map pin, and I have a callout method assigned to it etc. so I want my new view to function the same as this pin view. How would I go about this? I can't seem to find anything that teaches me how to do this: would I have to create the circle as an overlay and handle the drawing in the map view controller?

Comment: whether do you want a solid circle instead of the pin? am i correct?

Comment: That's it. A solid circle with a number placed where the pin would be.

Comment: Do you want the circle to stay a constant size like an annotation or scale with the zoom level?  For an annotation, the custom annotation view in the WeatherMap sample app can be adapted to show a circle with a number.